# The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have the next NGINX proxy configuration

```
http {
    server_tokens off;
server {
    listen     7443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/star.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/star.key;
    location /prometheus/ {
      auth_basic           "Prometheus";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      # I leave this hardcoded for now
      proxy_pass http://prometheus:9090/prometheus/;
   }

    location / {
      auth_basic           "Prometheus";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      # I leave this hardcoded for now
      proxy_pass http://alertmanager:9093;
   }
 }
}
events {}
```

If I enter in browser URL without specification of HTTPS by using port 7443, I get:

```
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

For example: prometheus.example.com:7443/prometheus/
or 
prometheus.example.com:7443/#/alerts/

How can I make NGINX redirect to HTTPS automatically if I specify such URLs without HTTPS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually the solution was pretty straightforward. In server section under "listen" string I was needed to add only:

```
error_page 497 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;
```

497 code is HTTP Request Sent to HTTPS Port.
error_page handles this code and redirects to https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;

where:

$host is reserved variable which represents hostname on which NGINX is being run.

$server_port is reserved variable which represents listining port which is declared in server section.

$request_uri is reserverd variable which represents full original request URI (with arguments).

Answer (score 1):

When you enter `prometheus.example.com:7443/prometheus/` browser tries to send http request. Try `https://prometheus.example.com:7443/prometheus/`.

Comment: Thank you I knew it, but the problem which I wanted to solve was a little bit another. Please read my latest answer, since I've already found a solution.